# disable-output-escaping=yes is not working in the below case

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have below sample xml  `

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TDX>
<AddressData>
    <AddressDetail>
<Address FieldName="ReceiverAddress1" FieldValue="CNR TOORONG &amp; TOORAK RD"/>
    </AddressDetail>    
</AddressData>
</TDX>
```

And the XSLT that transforms this xml into desired format. I have taken a single node here

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ConNotes>
      <ConNote>
        <ReceiverAddress1>
          <xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping="yes" select="TDX/AddressData/AddressDetail/Address[@FieldName='ReceiverAddress1']/@FieldValue"/>
        </ReceiverAddress1>
      </ConNote>
    </ConNotes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whenever I try to transform the XML using xslt I get the error "Whitespace is not allowed at this location". I have figured it out that this error is due to the special character & present in the FieldValue attribute of address node.
I have tried disable-output-escpaing="yes" but it's not working as expected.
I have used "output method="xml"" in the XSLT file.
Please help me with this. I am using XML notepad for applying the transformation.
I am expecting the output xml like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ConNotes>
- <ConNote>
  <ReceiverAddress1>CNR TOORONG & TOORAK RD</ReceiverAddress1> 
  </ConNote>
  </ConNotes>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a complete XSLT that demonstrates the problem please? Also, can you show your expected output? And finally, how are you actually performing the transformation? Thank you!

Comment: @TimC I have edited the question. Please check now.

Comment: Why are you trying to produce invalid XML as your output? The ampersand needs to be escaped to make it valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` then the ampersand `&` in the output is not escaped as entity `&amp;`. The output is then **not a well-formed XML document**. When you open the result XML in IE you will get the "Whitespace..." error.

The fix is trivial: Just remove the `disable-output-escaping="yes"` and 
the output will be well-formed:

```
<ConNotes>
<ConNote>
<ReceiverAddress1>CNR TOORONG &amp; TOORAK RD</ReceiverAddress1> 
</ConNote>
</ConNotes>
```